# What is the Planck Pressure?

Tags: pressure, quantum-gravity, singularities, physical-constants, absolute-units

What exactly is the [Planck Pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units)? According to wikipedia the Planck pressure "is not found except for shortly after the big bang or in a black hole". But wouldn't the pressure inside a black hole equal infinity?

Comment: Wikipedia also states "The Planck density is thought to be the upper limit of density.", which I would also like an elaboration of